# Dual boot of Xubuntu 21.10 and Windows 10 Home on SSD 128 GB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, xubuntu, ssd

Windows 10 Home came with the computer on SSD 128 GB.
I use Xubuntu to work every day but I use Windows 10 Home a few times a year.
I'd like Windows 10 to sleep quietly in the SSD.
Is it possible to do dual boot on SSD 128 GB ?
And how many gigabytes should be divided for Windows 10 Home and Xubuntu ?

Comment: Dual boot will work, but if you only need Windows a few times per year, consider using a VM instead.

Comment: You need to check how much space is Windows using now. I’d leave about 10GB free for the Windows partition and use the rest for Xubuntu. If that is not enough uninstall any apps you don’t really need in Windows before you start and check the space it’s using again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partition 256 GB SSD for dual Boot, Windows 10 + Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160473/partition-256-gb-ssd-for-dual-boot-windows-10-ubuntu-19-04)