# Dual boot Ubuntu 22.04.03 : how to free more space on disk

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, disk

I recently dual booted my Lenovo i7 windows computer to use Ubuntu 22.04.03. I initially freed 100 go of memory for the OS but I realize that it is not much. My computer is 1 To. I understand that I need to boot in windows to partition my disk, but the subsequent steps seem tedious. More precisely, I wonder :

1. How much space should I leave on windows for it to be safe, since I don't plan on using it very much. Is 75 Go enough?
2. Once I have made a disk partition that is not allocated, how can I merge it with the one where Ubuntu is? (or maybe it can only be done by re-installing...)
3. I saw that you can partitioned the disk so that Ubuntu OS and my home user are on different partitions. What would then be the advantage of doing such thing, and could it cause problems with e.g. packages/software that are on the OS disk, and not on the user disk, or vice-versa?
4. I have made a .txt file for all the modifications I made in my OS (e.g. sudo commands), but I don't have command lines for initial software installation. Will I have to re-install everything that is not on this file?

I would appreciate overall any guide/indications for selecting disks when rebooting Ubuntu.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Partition 256 GB SSD for dual Boot, Windows 10 + Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160473/partition-256-gb-ssd-for-dual-boot-windows-10-ubuntu-19-04)

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in a single post. Pick one of these to ask, and post a new question please. Note that your first question isn't on topic here, we don't support Windows. On the whole, you might want to delete and ask your questions on [su] instead since they seem to touch on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

> How much space should I leave on windows for it to be safe, since I don't plan on using it very much. Is 75 Go enough?

We only deal with Ubuntu so you need to ask Windows users that one.

> Once I have made a disk partition that is not allocated, how can I merge it with the one where Ubuntu is? (or maybe it can only be done by re-installing...)

The tool for that is [Gparted](https://gparted.org/). Partitions next to each other can be merged. Otherwise you need to move the empty space to the partition in the direction it needs to go (so enlarge with empty space, then shrink and add empty space to the next partition and so on).

> I saw that you can partitioned the disk so that Ubuntu OS and my home user are on different partitions. What would then be the advantage of doing such thing, and could it cause problems with e.g. packages/software that are on the OS disk, and not on the user disk, or vice-versa?

It makes re-installing a lot easier. BUT not /home on a different partition: the directories in /home/$USER on a separate partition: easy backup, easy re-installation, and useable on multiple operating systems (since that partition can be NTFS/exFAT). All you need to do is format / and mount the datapartition.

> I have made a .txt file for all the modifications I made in my OS (e.g. sudo commands), but I don't have command lines for initial software installation. Will I have to re-install everything that is not on this file?

Not perse. But if you need the initial software re-install is easiest.

The default can be installed by installing the desktop metapackage.

Vanilla gnome: `sudo apt install gnome-session`
Cinnamon: `sudo apt install cinnamon-desktop-environment`
KDE: `sudo apt install kde-standard`
XFCE `sudo apt install xfce4 xfce4-goodies`
LXDE `sudo apt install lxde`
LXQt `sudo apt install lxqt`

There will be more of these. And you can have more than 1 installed where you select the one you want at login.

Comment: Thank you very much!!