# Missing disk space after upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10. How come?

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, windows, drive

I have a problem with my disk space on Ubuntu.
I'll say some facts:

- When I installed Ubuntu, I told Ubuntu to take 25GB of space.
- I installed Ubuntu on my D:\ Drive, which is NOT the drive on which is my Windows 7
- I have a dual boot ( Ubuntu and windows 7 )
- I saw that I am low in disk space today, never checked before.
- Yesterday, I updated from 11.04 to 11.10
- I heard that Ubuntu takes 700mb ( this is why I don't understand what is happening )
- My D:\ Drive has about 15GB remaining.

My questions are:

- What took all the 24GBs ?
- How to add space to the home folder ?
- And why does my Disk Usage Analyzer shows that there is 136.7 GB in the file system? :

Disk Usage Analyzer screenshot:

[image]

Thanks to anyone who answers :)

Answer (score 3):

First off, you have asked 3 questions instead of one. Please do create separate questions in the future. Also, it would help you get better answers if you add more information to your questions. Now on to answering your questions,

***What took all the 24 GB?***

You stated in the question yourself that you allocated 25 GB for Ubuntu. So well, there you go.

***How do I add more space to my home folder?***

There are already a few questions on the site similar to that, you can take a look at [How can I add more disk space to my home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28561/how-can-i-add-more-disk-space-to-my-home-directory)

***Why does Disk Usage Analyzer show there is 136.7 GB in my filesystem?***

The Disk Usage Analyzer is showing the entire hard-drive. Everything when mounted in Linux falls under a single root in a tree-like structure. Hence it reports to you that the entire filesystem is 136.7GB in size. Moreover, this is the Disk *Usage* Analyzer, you'd have better info about the size occupied by your partitions and all with a tool like Disk Utility or  **[gparted [image: software_center_icon]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gparted)** . I've attached a screenshot below to show you what I mean.

[image: disk_utility_screenshot]