# How add space to my home folder?

Tags: 11.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add more disk space to my home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28561/how-can-i-add-more-disk-space-to-my-home-directory)

I'm new to Ubuntu and I need help, I created a partition for my folder of 2GB but I'm determined to stay with Linux. I want to delete my other two NTFS partitions that I have one for my files and one for Windows 7. The problem is that I don't want ro delete any of my photos or documents.

What can I do?

Please help me I don't know so much about this but I like the operating system, the problem is that I fear losing my information.

Comment: Did you take a look at this question? - [How can I add more disk space to my home directory?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/28561/how-can-i-add-more-disk-space-to-my-home-directory)

Comment: read up on 'symlink'. I have a 5 Gb /home/{user}/ that has the directories symlinked to another disc. Easy as pie ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can manage partitions by booting a live (desktop) Ubuntu CD and running gparted.

You will probably need to turn swap off, you can do this from the gparted window or manually.

```
sudo swapoff
```

See : http://gparted.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=help-manual

If you have data you do not want to loose, back it up first. Backups are always a good idea and although resizing and moving partitions is relatively safe, there is always a chance for data loss.

There are several backup options, see

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an external hard drive that you can backup up the files you want to keep from the NTFS partitions?

Once your files are backed up you need to boot Ubuntu from a USB pen or CD (as you did when you were installing it) as the partitions will need to be unmounted when altering them. Once you are booted in a live USB you can use the partition manager that is included to delete the NTFS partitions and resize the Ubuntu partition (probably EXT4).

---

I DONT recommend the following as you could lose all your files but if you are unable to backup you files first then you could boot a live USB then shrink the NTFS partitions and grow the Ubuntu partition (this will take a long time). Then boot the installed version of Ubuntu and copy your files over from the NTFS. Then boot a live USB, delete the NTFS and grow the EXT4.