# Resize file system partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

How Can I add more space to my FileSystem partition.

I read some answers here but this answers not work with me and this is the problem :

When I boot from CD live, Gparted give me the choose for minimize the Filesystem partition, but doesn't give me  the choose to add more space !!

Notes :

- I have unallocated space.
- I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 and I boot from Ubuntu 13.10 -_-
- This the Gparted screen shoot [image: screenshot] :

Comment: Have you read this yet ~ http://askubuntu.com/questions/28561/how-can-i-add-more-disk-space-to-my-home-directory

I have never tried to resize from Gparted. Last time I resized a partition I used Partition Magic, and that was a long, long time ago.

Comment: This isn't what I need, because I can't copy all things in the home folder to the new partition because Home folder size bigger than the new partition size -_-

Comment: In any case it is very risky to do such stuff without backups. If gparted doesn't give you the option there will be a reason for it. Maybe it's just not enough space to fill a block or the space it not adjacent to the partition.

Comment: I don't know what I should do, and the problem I want reinstall Ubuntu because I have installed lot of important programs ... :(

Comment: Edit your question to show us a screenshot of your disk layout from gparted.

Comment: You can only extend the partition if there is un-allocated disk to its side. In your case 'dev/sda8' is in between your file system and un-allocated space. So if want to extend the file system first move the partition 'dev/sda8' to right and try extending the file system. Be careful when you move the partition it may result in data lost. Tell me if it works

Comment: I will post it in answer mark it as write answer. Will you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only extend the partition if there is un-allocated disk to its side.

In your case `dev/sda8` is in between your file system and un-allocated space. So if want to extend the file system first move the partition `dev/sda8` to right and try extending the file system.

**Be careful when you move the partition it may result in data lost.**

Tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem.. Even though you have unallocated space in your drive, it is not right next to the partition whose size you want to increase. Try moving (NOT-increasing the size of) sda8 to the right, and try resizing your file-system partition.